# The wait queue for acquiring a connection to server ******* is full. [MongoDB]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mlab

I'm having this error... I'm using ASP.NET Core with the last version of driver C#.

> The wait queue for acquiring a connection to server [server:port] is
>   full.

**Failed Method:**

> MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool+AcquireConnectionHelper.CheckingOutConnection

**Call Stack:**

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoWaitQueueFullException
MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool+AcquireConnectionHelper.CheckingOutConnection
MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool+<AcquireConnectionAsync>d__35.MoveNext
[external code]
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer+<GetChannelAsync>d__40.MoveNext
[external code]
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1+<ExecuteAsync>d__107.MoveNext
[external code]
MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor+<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext
[external code]
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1+<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__59`1.MoveNext
[external code]
MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions+<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext
[external code]
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext
```

I have a Singleton DB Context.

**Example API Controller:**

```
[HttpPut]
        [Route("UpdatePosition")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePosition([FromBody]AreaDto dto)
        {
            var idUser = User.GetUserId();

            if (dto == null)
                return HttpBadRequest("Fail request");

            _service.IdUser = idUser;


            var item = await _service.UpdateAreaPosition(dto);

            if (item == null)
                return HttpBadRequest("Fail request");

            return Ok(item);
        }
```

**Service method:**

```
public async Task<string> UpdateAreaPosition(AreaDto dto)
        {
            var area = await GetArea(dto);

            if (area == null || dto.Position?.PositionLeft == null || dto.Position.PositionTop == null) return null;

            area.Position.PositionLeft = dto.Position.PositionLeft;
            area.Position.PositionTop = dto.Position.PositionTop;
            await _repositoryAreas.Update(area);
            return area.Id;
        }
```

The GetArea and Update method are from a Repository Pattern:

**Update method:**

```
public virtual async Task<T> Update(T entity)
    {
        await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => entity.Id.Equals(x.Id), entity, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
        return entity;
    }
```

**Get Area Method:**

```
 private async Task<Area> GetArea(AreaDto dto)
        {
            var area = await _repositoryAreas.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == dto.Id);

            if (area == null)
                return null;


            return area;

        }
```

I have many other methods using mongoDB, but this is an example...

**Instance class IMongoDatabse:**

```
private static IMongoDatabase GetDatabaseFromUrl(MongoUrl url)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(url);
            return client.GetDatabase(url.DatabaseName); // WriteConcern defaulted to Acknowledged
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Saleem I have updated the question... thanks

Comment: .net Core is not 100% compatible with full framework and I'm not sure if MongoDB driver is optimized for it yet. However I'll dig into it and post my finding.

Comment: Thanks @Saleem In the official documentation says that Mongo C# Driver works fine with .NET Core... I have found that: http://blog.mlab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/

Comment: I believe it's not fully supported yet. See jira. https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CSHARP-1177

Comment: Maybe, I think the error could be in how I have created the DI of Repository: services.AddScoped<IRepository<Area>, MongoRepository<Area>>(); Do I need to change it to AddSingleton? Thanks @Saleem

Comment: @Saleem One datail, I use full dnx 451, that supports MongoDb C# Driver

Comment: See thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-csharp/gkhOrhISuPA/3czqyDnBdW4J

Comment: @Saleem Thanks!! I have added this param to my connection string: &waitQueueMultiple=10000, do you think it solve my problem? Thanks again!!