# Not saving data in IRepository pattern

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I'm using Repository pattern in a ASP.NET Core RC1 (dnx full CLR451) Update 1 web project. I'm having a issue very strange...

Technical information: I'm using MongoDB with C# Driver and I have a cluster in mLab).

I register my DI repositories in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRepository<MyEntity>, MongoRepository<MyEntity>>();
```

The MongoRepository, has this private variable and constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// MongoCollection field.
/// </summary>
private readonly IMongoCollection<T> _collection;

/// <summary>    
/// Initializes a new instance of the MongoRepository class.
/// Uses the Default App/Web.Config connectionstrings to fetch the connectionString and Database name.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Default constructor defaults to "MongoServerSettings" key for connectionstring.</remarks>
public MongoRepository(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    : this(appSettings.Value.ConnectionString)
{

}

/// <summary>        
/// Initializes a new instance of the MongoRepository class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="connectionString">Connectionstring to use for connecting to MongoDB.</param>
public MongoRepository(string connectionString)
{
    _collection = Util<TKey>.GetCollectionFromConnectionString<T>(connectionString);
}
```

And at the end I'm creating a MongoClient by each repository:

```
/// <summary>        
/// Creates and returns a MongoDatabase from the specified url.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">The url to use to get the database from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a MongoDatabase from the specified url.</returns>
private static IMongoDatabase GetDatabaseFromUrl(MongoUrl url)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(url);
    return client.GetDatabase(url.DatabaseName); // WriteConcern defaulted to Acknowledged
}
```

If I use AddScoped instead AddSingleton in my repository DI, I have errors with connection pool ([check my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135302/the-wait-queue-for-acquiring-a-connection-to-server-is-full-mongodb))

My string behavior is that for example, 30 o 40 users is working together in my web app at the same time in a classroom, they have noticed that some times the data is not saving. My team has not detected this issue working, but we can test 30 o 40 together users (stress test and Unit Test has been passed).

My question is... is this a normal behavior? Make sense that I have problems with my MongoDb Client or Repository conflict working many users together? Do I need to change how MongoClient is instaced? Maybe another singleton?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be anything, really. Are there any error messages on the client or the MongoDB server? If not then try to set the MongoDB profiling level to 2 (I'm thinking slow running queries being dropped), see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/#db.setProfilingLevel. If still don't get any information then it might help to install Fiddle. Post your additional findings here at SO, please.

Comment: The only error that I have is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37135302/the-wait-queue-for-acquiring-a-connection-to-server-is-full-mongodb